# Signal R and AJAX not getting updates from API

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, .net-core, signalr

So I followed this quick guide from the MS site for building a SignalR app :
[SignalR App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)

I would of thought that I could use a local API to watch the count change after adding a row to it in real time. I used AJAX for this:

```
function getALL() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/GetCount',
    contentType: 'application/json ; charset:utf-8',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById("messageList").innerHTML = data[0].Count;
    }
  });
}
```

Of course initiated hub with: `var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/chatHub").build();`

```
connection.on("ReceiveMessage", function () {
  getALL();
});

connection.start().then(function () {
  getALL(); 
  connection.invoke("SendMessage").catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
}).catch(function (err) {
  return console.error(err.toString()); 
});
```

Now the above code works and shows me the data the first time, but when I add another row, nothing happens. What am I missing? The onclick event in the MS example works. But not if I try to load it without no events.

My Hub:

```
    public class ChatHub : Hub
    {
        private IHubContext<ChatHub> _hubContext;

        public ChatHub(IHubContext<ChatHub> hubContext) { _hubContext = hubContext; }

        public async Task SendMessage()
        {
            await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage");
        }
    }
}
```

Am I adding the AJAX in the wrong place? Is my hub missing a Entity Model? If so, why would it when I'm calling a local API.

I also loaded the hub in the Startup.cs file as advised:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("/chatHub");
            endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
        });
```

I'm trying this with net Core 3.1 as well. Any suggestions are helpful. I thought this would be a simple example to modify, but I have had no luck with it yet. Thank you all.

Comment: Where is the code, calling sendMessage?

Comment: @Nikolaus - good catch - I added it now

Comment: Can you add the code, where you add a new row?

Comment: In this brief example, I did not add rows, I just added the count integer from the API to the #messageList ID as seen in the ajax call. The idea was to update the count every time a row was added in the database and not technically in the syntax with table rows.

Comment: How do you add rows in the database? With a webapp too? Then you have to add signalR and the sendMessage-Syntax in the other webapp. If not, there is hardly any possibility to use SignalR to update your view... maybe you should frequently make a call to getall() every five seconds or so.

Comment: No, as of now I was doing it strictly from the database. I wanted to see the row count increase as I added them. That would come later. But because this seemed like a fairly easy exercise, I thought it would increment as well regardless if it was from a web app or directly from the DB.

Answer (score 1):

You need the hub to be notified, when there is a change like this:

```
connection.invoke("SendMessage").catch(function (err) {
    return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

And you need this not, after starting the connection, but after every add of an row.
Edit:
To show you a bit, of what is needed:
1. You need an event in an signalR-Client, where the row is added and the code before is run.
2. you Need a (second or same) signalR-Client, that is notified, like you already have.

You can’t see changes in the database, if you only add a row directly.
You have to add the row in the Frontensegeln and notify the Hub in your client-side application.

Comment: I did not think they needed a parameter added to them, I have seen examples without them. Also if I did add a parameter - which i did try as well - where would I call the invoke method? In the ajax success callback or in the on.start? I did this in on the "on('ReceiveMessage')", but I got infinite loops.

Comment: @AnalyzingTasks you need this in addNewRow in the callback.

Comment: So is it correct that I added it to the getALL() function under the success callback? That's where I'm confused. Because when I click on the button function that was provided in the article - it does update the value after clicking it. But I do not wish a on click event, but a on update to the value once a row has been added to the database. So it seems that I may be calling the invoke method in the wrong location.

Comment: It is the wrong location in the getall-function. The hub has to be notified, when there is a change, not when there is a new observer.

Comment: I see - so does the change have to be an event then? I thought I have seen examples with an onChange function in the back end from the hub. In this article example the change happens on click, so to replicate it the even onChange, I'm assuming you need to send the parameter to notify the hub that the value has changed? I have not see any article on signalR with this type of scenario, all I have seen are onclick events, or utilizing the older signalR framework with controllers creating API calls, which I do not want if there is already an API in place.

Comment: By the way, I did add the function on the start connection and then after adding the new value on success callback from ajax. I get infinite loops. I don't think that is what its supposed to do correct? Would you be able to provide a quick example then by where i need to call the invoke method. I think that is where I'm failing to add this correctly.

Comment: OK - so they need to go hand in hand for SignalR to catch the addition of the new row as an event, then the update is what will update the count because it now knows something was added. I was not aware of that specification with SignalR for use with a database. I will try that then. Many thanks for making me aware of this.